# Condition implying that $E(X|\mathcal{C}_1)=E(X|\mathcal{C}_2)$ when $\mathcal{C}_1\subseteq\mathcal{C}_2$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have the following corollary in my notes but I don't see how it follows from law of total probability:

**Corollary.** Assume that $\mathcal{C}_1\subseteq\mathcal{C}_2\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ are sub $\sigma$-fields and $E(X)$ exists. If a version of $E(X|\mathcal{C}_2)$ is $\mathcal{C}_1/\mathcal{B}^1$-measurable then $E(X|\mathcal{C}_2)$ is also a version of $E(X|\mathcal{C}_1)$.

In my notes the law of total probability stands as follows:

**Theorem.** If $\mathcal{C}_1\subseteq\mathcal{C}_2\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ are sub $\sigma$-fields and $E(X)$ exists, then $E(X|\mathcal{C}_1)$ is version of $E(E(X|\mathcal{C}_2)|\mathcal{C}_1)$.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I think you have some typos in your theorem probably...

Comment: Note that, if $\mathcal{C}_1\subseteq\mathcal{C}_2$, then $E(E(X|\mathcal{C}_2)|\mathcal{C}_1)=E(X|\mathcal{C}_1)$, and that, if furthermore $Y=E(X|\mathcal{C}_2)$ is $\mathcal{C}_1/\mathcal{B}^1$-measurable then $E(Y|\mathcal{C}_1)=Y$ almost surely. These two remarks put together answer your question.

Comment: Thank you @Did. The problem is that in my notes the claim is that $E(X|\mathcal{C}_1)$ is a version of $E(X|\mathcal{C}_2)$.

Comment: "A version of" refers to the fact that conditional expectations are only defined up to a null set, that is, if $Y=E(X\mid G)$ and if $P(Z=Y)=1$ with $Z$ $G$-measurable then $Z$ has all the required properties to be called $E(X\mid G)$ as well.

Comment: Oh I see. I am sorry, it was a dumb question!

Comment: What's c1/B-measurable?

Comment: @BCLC it means that inverse of any element in $\mathcal{B}$ is in $\mathcal{C}_1$.

Comment: Cupitor, okay but in beginning of advanced probability theory, random variables are supposed to take values in $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ or $(\overline{\mathbb R}, \mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R}))$ right? In your class, can random variables be, like complex, or something?

Answer (score 1):

What is $E[X|\mathcal C_1]$?

It is any random variable $Z$ that satisfies

1. $Z$ is $\mathcal C_1$-measurable.
2. $$\int_{C_1} E[X|\mathcal C_1] d\mathbb P = \int_{C_1} Z d\mathbb P$$

$$\forall C_1 \in \mathcal C_1$$

Is $E[X|\mathcal C_2]$ one of those $Z$'s?

1. $E[X|\mathcal C_2]$ is $\mathcal C_1$-measurable by assumption. (*)

2.

$$LHS = \int_{C_1} E[X|\mathcal C_1] d\mathbb P$$

$$ = \int_{\Omega} 1_{C_1} E[X|\mathcal C_1] d\mathbb P$$

$$ = \int_{\Omega} E[X1_{C_1}|\mathcal C_1] d\mathbb P$$

$$ = E[E[X1_{C_1}|\mathcal C_1]]$$

$$ = E[X1_{C_1}]$$

$$RHS = \int_{C_1} Z d\mathbb P$$

$$ = \int_{C_1} E[X|\mathcal C_2] d\mathbb P$$

$$ = \int_{\Omega} 1_{C_1} E[X|\mathcal C_2] d\mathbb P$$

$$ = E[1_{C_1}E[X|\mathcal C_2]]$$

$$ = E[E[X1_{C_1}|\mathcal C_2]]$$

$$ = E[X1_{C_1}]$$

I believe #2 does not make use of #1 unlike below

---

This is the formal way to go about this. I believe there's an intuitive way of thinking about it.

---

And of course there's the shortcut

$$E[X|\mathcal C_1] = E[E[X|\mathcal C_2]|\mathcal C_1]$$

$\because E[X|\mathcal C_2]$ is given to be $\mathcal C_1$-measurable $(*)$, we have

$$RHS = E[E[X|\mathcal C_2]|\mathcal C_1] \stackrel{(*)}{=} E[X|\mathcal C_2] E[1|\mathcal C_1] = E[X|\mathcal C_2] (1)$$

---

$(*)$ This is critical. There's no reason for $E[X|\mathcal C_2]$ to surely be $\mathcal C_1$-measurable otherwise because $\mathcal C_2$ is the bigger $\sigma-$field.